# How to set a recurrent alarm during begin and end times in Outlook 2010 e.g. a birthday reminder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, reminder

I have now set all my birthdays in calendar in Outlook 2010. The start and end date is the same. The times for **that day** starts at 09h00 and ends 21h00.

I want the alarm to go off at 18h00 hours, but do not know if it is possible. **(This is as a back-up in case we forget.)**

The times that are available in Outlook ends at 0 minutes i.e. if I set it, the alarm will go off at 09h00.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this PDF help?

[Oulook 2010 Calendar](http://www.hsc.wvu.edu/its/LC/Documents/HowTo/Outlook/Outlook_Calendar_2010.pdf)